# Restrict code execution based on a specific module

Tags: module

I will be passing a sheet back and forth to several users.  I want to make available certain programs that are tied to buttons located on the different sheets.  If I set aside certain users: admin, level1 each would be able to run code.

I had thought a convenient way would be to populate the modules with the restrictions, where access to the modules would be restricted by user.

- Module1: contains items open to all users
- Module2: contains all items that are restricted

When I write a new process, if I want to restrict it I place the code in module2.  So when someone hit the button it does not run.

thoughts!

thank you in advance.

I thought of placing code at beginning of each routine:

If Application.UserName <> "myname" Then
MsgBox "User " & Application.UserName & vbCrLf & "Macro Disabled"
End
End If

thought there might be a more elegant way

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You've only tagged this with [tag:module]. I'm guessing by the code in the question that this is a VBA question? Please [edit] to clarify.